# Sliding scale for rep abilities for new StackExchange sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange

There are questions that need editing on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), as with any other SO/SE site, but most of us start too low to do much about it.

Could we have some relaxed rep requirements in the Beta phase of the site, maybe a sliding scale based on site-rep-average or time?

Comment: I'd just flag as spam then.

Comment: @Jus, yep, that's what I did in the end, but I hate flagging spam things that aren't truly commercial spam.

Comment: @Lance some would argue that Evan's contributions are actually *worse* than commercial spam. The latter at least has a purpose.

Comment: Sweet 404 page.

Comment: Sorry, but what's your question? :)

Comment: It was just a discussion question born of frustration.  It can be closed as localized now, since all the discussion happened in the comments anyway.

Comment: Right, and when someone asks it in two years, and gets 500 exp for it - it will be a "different case" right?

Comment: @Lance please see my updated answer and make sure it's still "what you want"

Comment: @Evan, what frustrated me most about the question was the crappy grammar in the title that I couldn't fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe while in beta we should also relax the reputation restrictions. For instance:

Private beta:

- 1     Leave comments
- 1     Reduced advertising
- 1     Vote up
- 1     Flag offensive
- 1     Create new tags
- 1     Vote down (costs 1 rep)
- 1     Edit community wiki posts
- 1     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
- 1     Retag questions
- 300   Show total up and down vote counts
- 500   Edit other people's posts
- 1     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
- 2000 Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools

public beta:

- 50    Leave comments
- 200   Reduced advertising
- 15    Vote up
- 15    Flag offensive
- 10    Create new tags
- 100   Vote down (costs 1 rep)
- 100   Edit community wiki posts
- 250   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
- 200   Retag questions
- 300   Show total up and down vote counts
- 500   Edit other people's posts
- 500   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
- 3000 Delete closed questions, access to moderation tools

Then, during the public beta for every 30 days it ramps up closer to normal by say 50% closer to normal. And when the public beta is over, then it should basically be back to the normal amount. This would fix the bad problem of "how am I going to ever get 3k so I can start closing inappropriate questions!?" when the site has only been like for 2 weeks

Comment: I don't really like the idea of every time a site goes full having a slew of Meta questions asking why privileges have been removed *unfairly*.

Comment: I believe the limits already were lower, then raised to "normal" levels when the site went public.

Comment: @Chacha that's why I said "or maybe even a slow ramping up" so that basically for every month after the beta ends the reputation requirements get closer to "normal" until eventually it is normal.

Comment: @Jon everything but the bolded items are lower. look at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq oh wait nevermind. I was thinking of private beta.. Right now for public beta everything is "normal"

Comment: @Earlz currently your list is significantly different from the live reputation listings. Almost the entire list should be bold.

Comment: I think the only threshold that's currently lower than "normal" is "200 - Retag questions" which is usually 500.

Comment: @Chacha @Jon I wasn't aware that private beta and public beta had different numbers. Fixed now

Comment: I'd like the editing number to be lower, but it looks good.

Comment: @Lance well yes maybe it should be.. but it's just a simple example. give or take a few rep here or there.